# Where to find data sent by Google Analytics measurement protocol implementation?

Tags: google-analytics

A few days ago I implemented the "Measurement Protocol"  for Google Analytics on a page.  Where can I find this data in the Google Analytics reports?

Comment: Data should be visible in der standard reports (not all of them may show results, this depends on what data you passed in to the tracking call). If you do not see data then probably something went wrong with your implementation.

Comment: What data are you sending?    If you are sending pageview data, that will show up on the pageview report.   If you are sending ecommerce tracking, that will show up on that report.   Measurement protocol can be used for quite a variety of data that would appear in various places.